# Getting specific values from Web3js getPastEvents

Tags: web3js, contract-development, javascript, events

I would like to know how to pull the account value from returnValues: Result {} of this web3.eth.Contract

This code logs to the console just fine, but I have scoured documentation on objects and on web3js to find ways to transform this object to no avail. I have also tried filtering and topics
per https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id48 but have had no luck...

[image]

```
for (const element2 of lendingPairList) {
                  const eventPair = new web3.eth.Contract(PairContractABI, element2)
                        eventPair.getPastEvents("Deposit", {                          
                          fromBlock: 12867493,
                          toBlock: 'latest'
                      })
                      .then(events => console.log(events))
              .catch((err) => console.error(err));
                    }
                  }}      
                )}
              }
            )
          })
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `events` should be array of past event objects. So if you want to access the `account` value you should do it like this:

```
.then(function(events) {
    if (events.length) {
        for (var i = 0, len = events.length; i < len; i+=1) {
            console.log(events[i].returnValues.account);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great, you can accept my answer with the green check so others having the same issue can recognize the solution.